# How to return the list of Roles that the user has?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I followed the article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory and created an App role

The below endpoint uses users role to authorize

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TutorialController {

    @Autowired
    TutorialRepository tutorialRepository;

     @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('APPROLE_Admin', 'APPROLE_Contributor')")
    @GetMapping("/tutorials")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Tutorial>> getAllTutorials(@RequestParam(required = false) String title) {
        try {
            List<Tutorial> tutorials = new ArrayList<Tutorial>();
```

I want to introduce an additional Get Endpoint to return the list of Roles that the user has?

**Update: 25/05/2022**

I have added an additional mapping as mentioned below

```
@GetMapping("/roles")
public ResponseEntity<List<GrantedAuthority>> getRoles() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = (List<GrantedAuthority>) userDetails.getAuthorities();
    return (ResponseEntity<List<GrantedAuthority>>) authorities;
}
```

Getting the error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser
> cannot be cast to class
> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails

Comment: Share your both User and Role entity/class code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have set your security configuration up properly, you can get the current users' roles as below.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = userDetails.getAuthorities();
```

Comment: Getting the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails

Answer (score 1):

The GrantedAuthorities are available on the Authentication class, so once you have this you can call `getAuthorities()` directly and get back a Collection of `GrantedAuthorty`.

```
@GetMapping("/roles")
public ResponseEntity<List<GrantedAuthority>> getRoles() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return ResponseEntity.of(authentication.getAuthorities());
}
```

Comment: Getting the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity (java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: My apologies, I didn't pay close enough attention when I reworked your method, see my edits and try this.